# Parsing pagination in php

Tags: php

I'm working with indexing some news sites. A kind of news clipping.
I'm an amateur and curious. I'm not a programmer so the question may seem silly to anyone in the business. But if anyone can help, thank you.
The paging of the sites I was doing parsing was practically the same and I used this scheme:

```
$url = $ url. '/page/'. $s;

$next_url = $s + 1;
$prev_url = $s - 1;
if ($prev_url <= 0) {
$prev_url = 1;
}
```

The format was basically this:

```
http://example.com/politics/page/2
```

But yesterday I came across something different and I do not know how to page. I get this link format through `preg_match_all`:

```
http://www.example.com/browse-Politics-National-texts-1-date.html
```

This is the paging part:

```
-1-
```

This part is variable:

```
Political-National-texts
```

Any guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are asking for is parsing the url for the pagination and variable parts, you can use [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match) with the following regexp:

```
if (preg_match('/^http:\/\/www.example.com\/browse-([-a-zA-Z]+)-(\d+)-date\.html$/', $url, $matches)) {
    var_export($matches);
}
```

Then you will get the result:

```
array (
  0 => 'http://www.example.com/browse-Politics-National-texts-1-date.html',
  1 => 'Politics-National-texts',
  2 => '1',
)
```

The keys in `$matches` will be:

- 0: The entire match
- 1: The first matched group (the variable)
- 2: The second matched group (the pagination)

Comment: Would it be this?
`<?php
 $url   = $_GET['url'];
 if (preg_match('/^http:\/\/www.exemplo.com\/browse-([-a-zA-Z]+)-(\d+)-date\.html$/', $url, $matches)) {
    var_export($matches);
 }
 $link = 'http://www.exemplo.com/browse-'. $matches[1] .'-'.$s . '-date.html' ;
 $next_url = $s + 1;
 $prev_url = $s - 1;
 if ($prev_url <= 0) {
 $prev_url = 1;
 }

 ?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $url = 'http://www.example.com/browse-Politics-National-texts-1-date.html'
   $url_basename = basename($url); // extract `browse-Politics-National-texts-1-date.html`
   $url_exploded = explode('-',$url_basename); // make an array delimited by `-`
   array_pop($url_exploded);
   $url_page_number = array_pop($url_exploded); // get the 2nd element from back 
 ?>
```

Result:

$url_page_number = `1`

PS. Could make it shorter, but it's for educational purposes :-)

Comment: "Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given"